# Responsive, sortable Bootstrap thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'd like to format a list of thumbnails using Bootstrap 3 so that they are displayed in rows of 4 on large screens, 2 on smaller screens etc. Also, I need to be able to drag and drop the thumbnails to change their order.

So far I tried this markup

```
<ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled">
 <li class="thumbnail-container">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="...">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

styled up like this (LESS)

```
.thumbnails {
    .row;
    .clearfix;

    .thumbnail-container {
        .make-md-column(3);

        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            clear: left;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `clear` because the thumbnails are not of equal height.
I tried to implement sorting using jQuery UI Sortable and [this script](https://github.com/voidberg/html5sortable), but both ended up the same - when sorting, the rows of thumbnails would break too often, leaving gaps in the grid.

Can this be worked around somehow? I know I could use something like Masonry or Isotope, but it seems a huge overkill for me. The behaviour is the same in latest Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I really need an answer for the very same question !!

Answer (score -1):

Use the power of Bootstrap. You can do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="#sortable" class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="" alt="...">
            </a> 
        </div>

        ...

    </div>
</div>
```

The magic happens because of "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3". This basically tells that on extra small devices the thumb should take the full width (12/12) of the container; on small devices it should take half the width (6/12) and on medium and large screens it will take quarter (3/12) of the width.

**For more information:** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

---

If you want to drag and drop the thumbnails I suggest that you use a third party JavaScript to achieve this. For example you can use "jQuery UI Sortable" like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    });
</script>
```

**For more information refer to:** http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Yes, I tried this and my layout got broken during the dragging. Also, the layout breaks for thumbnails with non-equal heights.

Comment: The question is How tu use something like jquery sortable with bootstrap grid ( here thumbnail in column ), so you just don't answer the question.